# Concatenate a range with values in between

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, concatenation

I work with ranged data and want to populate a cell that includes values at set increments between the min and maximum. For example, the minimum outer diameter is 1 1/16" and the maximum outer diameter is 1 11/32". I want to populate a third cell that includes each end plus all the values in between by the 32th of an inch: 1 1/16";1 3/32";1 1/8";1 5/32";1 3/16";1 7/32";1 1/4";1 9/32";1 5/16";1 11/32"

Can I do this in Excel 2007?

So far, I'm just copying and pasting from a master, semi-colon delimited list I have of all values in-between 1 1/64th and 2" and then going back and copying and replacing "1 " with "2 " and adding them to the string and so on.

I just tried Madball73's VBA code. I was able to get it to generate values iff the whole number value was the same for each limit and I removed the ". For example, I tried 1 1/64 to 1 1/4 (and changed the increment to 0.015625 since this one was to the 64th). The VBA code returned: ";1  1/64";1  1/32";1  3/64";1  1/16";1  5/64";1  3/32";1  7/64";1  1/8";1  9/64";1  5/32";1 11/64";1  3/16";1 13/64";1  7/32";1 15/64";1  1/4"

Getting closer!

Update: Okay, with quite a bit of tweaking and adding the ultimate " through concatenation and trimming the preceding ";, I'm able to get this to work.

Update 2: it doesn't seem to be working any more :(

Comment: It's certainly not a trivial problem. I kind of doubt anyone will come up with a worksheet function solution, but this can be done in VBA with some effort. Are you open to a VBA solution?

Comment: Yes - I do this often enough and on large enough databases that I could certainly do it.

Comment: Do you have a maximum number of values you would be dealing with?  i.e. can one assume that you'll never have more than a 1 inch gap? (32 values)?

Comment: Unfortunately not and it is variable. Sometimes the ranges are 2-7"

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, please [edit] your question to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a custom VBA function for you.  Use it by setting your formula:  `=IterateSizes(value(a1),value(a2))`

```
Function IterateSizes(btmSize, topSize)
rtnValue = ""
incr = 0.03125

For i = btmSize To topSize Step incr
    fraction = Trim(Excel.WorksheetFunction.Text(i, "# ??/??"))
    rtnValue = rtnValue & """;" & fraction
Next i

IterateSizes = rtnValue
End Function
```

Note. It was quickly thrown together and works for the few inputs I gave it (which did not include the double-quotes).  But, this is not fully tested does not handle invalid inputs, is not boundary tested, etc but is a starting point.

Comment: How would I do this for increments of 0.01" and non-fractions?

Comment: change incr to 0.01 and the Text second parameter to something like "0.00"

Comment: I've tried this:
Function IterateSizes2(btmSize, topSize)
rtnValue = ""
incr = 0.01

For i = btmSize To topSize Step incr
    Text = Trim(Excel.WorksheetFunction.Text(i, "?.??"))
    rtnValue = rtnValue & """;"
Next i

IterateSizes2 = rtnValue
End Function

Comment: I tried putting in 0.00 for the ?.??, but that didn't work. Ugh. Just not getting it today.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler, non-VBA option here - [**Concatenate a cell range without vba in excel**](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2011/02/09/concatenate-a-cell-range-without-vba-in-excel/)

There are the key steps. Follow that link for images, comments and other tricks.

> ### Create delimiting character
>
> It would be great if we could have a character separating values. Here
>   is how:
>
> - Select cell B2.
> - Type =A1:A50&", " in formula bar.
> - Edit: Depending on your regional settings, try this: =TRANSPOSE(A1:A50)&", "
> - Press F9.
> - Delete curly brackets in formula bar.
> - Delete last delimiting character.
> - Type =Concatenate( in front of all characters in formula bar.
> - Type ) after last character in formula bar.
> - Press Enter

---

I do this quite a lot and I find this slight modification to be more convenient (Office 2016):

- As above, enter something like `=A1:A50&" "` then press F9
- Delete the `={` from the start and the `}` from the end, then press enter
- Find and replace (`ctrl-H`) `";"` with `"&"`
- Add `=` to the start of the cell