# Concatenate a range with a conditional seperator

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking for something similar to [this trick for concatenating a range with a seperator](https://superuser.com/a/962644/112639), but I want the output to include a special character on the item on the range that is for this row.

For example, starting with this:

```
Fruit      #
------------
Apples   100
Oranges   80
Pears     50
```

...I want a formula that can create a row like this:

```
Fruit      #             Output
------------------------------------------
Apples   100   >Apples -- Oranges -- Pears
Oranges   80   Apples -- >Oranges -- Pears
Pears     50   Apples -- Oranges -- >Pears
```

This example is massively simplified... my actual problem has hundreds of rows, needs to be repeated many times for many sheets, and is about creating precise-specification input for a different program, but the essence of the problem is the same. Something that can automate the output in the simple example above will solve my more complex problem.

---

I suppose want I want is something like `=TRANSPOSE(A1:A10)&IF($THIS=A2," -- >"," -- ")` where `$THIS` somehow indicates the item in the array that is being looked at when `F9` evaluates it... is anything like that even possible?

Comment: what is the purpose of having the numbers 100,80 and 50?

Comment: you want 100s of Output cells to contain an identical string with 100s of Fruit values concatenated (with delimiters.), which differ only by having the Fruit in column one marked with an extra character?

Comment: More or less yes, it's an unusual request, but that's the requirement of the system it's going to be input into. There's a little more to it than that but each row has to have the whole set, ordered, with that row's item marked with a special character

Comment: This is not possible with a single worksheet function. You are looking at a VBA solution here.

Comment: Can you just build the string and then do a REPLACE of A2 with ">"&A2 ?

Comment: @ScarletManuka that's a brilliant idea, great lateral thinking. Can't try it out right now but will test it later

Answer (score 1):

Using VBA:

```
Public Function markitem(itemrange As Range, item As String)
    markitem = ""
    i = 0
    itemlength = itemrange.Rows.Count
    result = ""
    For i = 1 To itemlength
        actualitem = itemrange.item(i)
        If actualitem = item Then
            actualitem = "<" & actualitem
        End If
        result = result & actualitem & " -- "
    Next i
    If i <> 0 Then
        markitem = Left(result, Len(result) - 3)
    End If   
End Function
```

Supposing your data starts on cell `A1`then in cell `C1`you have to put `=markitem($A$1:$A$3;A1)` and copy down the formula on column C.

To use this code go to Macros / VBA, insert a new module under *ThisWorkbook* and paste the code on the right side.